# Указатель на функцию и передача параметров

Tags: c++

Функции:

```
string foo(string a,...)
{
    cout << "[" << a << "]" << endl << ....;

}
void out(string(*sptr)(string a))
{
    cout << ...;
}
```

Вызов:

```
foo("1a", "2a");
out(foo);
```

Вывод:
foo:

[1a]

2a

out:

1a2a

Можно как-то сделать, чтобы функция **out** автоматически считывала параметры функции **foo**: Кол-во и типы? А после выводить в cout

Comment: Ничего не понял. Объясните нормально, что вы пытаетесь сделать и зачем.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat В функции **foo** может быть неограниченное кол-во параметров, например, string. В main я ввожу неограниченное кол-во параметров, после в функции foo, 1ый параметр выводится в скобках(как в примере), потом новая строка и все остальные параметры в ряд. В функции **out** я хочу считать все параметры и вывести просто в консоль. То есть, те параметры, что указал в foo вывести в out

Comment: Для этого нужно, чтобы `foo` куда-то сложила свои аргументы, например в глобальную переменную-строку (что не очень красиво). Но тогда передавать `foo` в `bar` больше не нужно. Еще нужно, собственно, научиться писать [функции с переменным числом аргументов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а именно, чтобы out сама считывала невозможно?

Comment: Вы намекаете на использование шаблона? Представьте на секунду, что то, что вы хотите, возможно — как при этом должен выглядеть ваш код и результат его работы?

Comment: Без содействия `foo` ничего нельзя сделать. Это очень странная просьба. Вы так и не объяснили, *зачем* это нужно.

Comment: А передать вектор? Или std::vector<std::variant> ?

Comment: Функция `out` в вопросе не может принимать указать на функцию `foo` из-за несоответствия типов. Однако она и так знает о единственном параметре указателя на функцию `sptr`, который она может принимать.